# Delete non numbers in row in Panda Python

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying do delete or replace all cells that aren't numbers in a column.

I used the code below:

```
if  file[[Coluna_Vaos]] is not float() or int():
ColVao = file[[Coluna_Vaos]].replace(**"-" or "!"**, np.NaN)
```

But I have to show every type that I don't want. If exist a variable for that that contain all things except numbers would be useful.

Resuming: I want to remove everything that is not a number on that row. I would appreciate if somebody could let the solution for other example, like check and rip if that is another thing besides strings.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pd.to_numeric` with `errors='coerce'` and then replace the NaN values or drop those rows.

```
df['newcol'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Coluna_Vaos'], errors='coerce')
df = df.dropna(subset=['Coluna_Vaos'])

# or
df['newcol'] = df['newcol'].fillna(0)
```

Comment: file['Vãos'] = pd.to_numeric(file["I"], errors = 'coerce')
print(file['Vãos'])

Gives: TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index